# Como fazer a mensagem ficar centralizada e piscar na tela em C++?

Tags: c++, console

Como fazer essa mensagem piscar na tela, ficar centralizada e como mudar a cor da mensagem?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;
    string mensagem;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    cout << "Digite um palavara: " ;
    cin >> mensagem;

        cout << "***************************" "\n";
        cout << "***************************" "\n";
        cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
        cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
        cout<< "***""\t"<<mensagem<<"\t***""\n";
        cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
        cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
        cout << "***************************" "\n";
        cout << "***************************" "\n";


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Se por acaso você está se referindo ao atributo `BLINK` de texto no console, isto é característica de código legado que fazia uso da lib `conio.h` da antiga Borland, agora embarcadero: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/textattr_xml.html.
Esta funcionalidade vem dos [antigamente difundidos modos VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para centralizar é fácil. Estou vendo como fazer piscar, o que já vi que não é tão simples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Center(string str) {
   int espacos = (int)((21 - str.length())/2);
   return string(espacos, ' ') + str + string(espacos + (str.length() > espacos * 2 ? 1 : 0), ' ');
}

int main() {
    string mensagem;
    cout << "Digite um palavara: ";
    cin >> mensagem;

    cout << "***************************" "\n";
    cout << "***************************" "\n";
    cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
    cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
    cout<< "***" << Center(mensagem) << "***""\n";
    cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
    cout << "***                     ***" "\n";
    cout << "***************************" "\n";
    cout << "***************************" "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/0o4MQM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CenterMessage). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/CenterMessage.cpp). A cor não funciona nele.

Pelo que entendi para piscar tem que fazer um *loop* trocando a cor por um *timer* mas deve ter uma forma melhor.

Comment: Essa questão me levou a vidas passadas. O único contexto no qual piscar no console é trivial foi na época que aprendi C e C++ no Turbo C++ em Windows 95 quando ainda havia o modo MS-DOS real.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode

Comment: @pepper_chico é, nesta época era mais fácil. Na verdade eu acho que deve existir um modo de console no Windows mais fácil de fazer isto. E provavelmente até o jeito antigo ainda funciona. Mas você tem razão que mandar algo ficar piscando assim não faz muito sentido. Bons tempos, tudo era mais fácil, agora a gente procura problemas para aplicar soluções que criaram :)

Comment: Uma resposta interessante seria uma aplicação exemplo no contexto do modo texto VGA, acho que vale uma pesquisada :)

Comment: Existem escolas que ainda estão neste ambiente pelo Brasil afora, não duvido.